# Is it possible to cast a string as int to get the value converted?

Tags: c, string, casting, integer

It would be nice to cast a string (array of chars) to an int when reading from files or taking input is this possible.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 500

int main(void)
{
 FILE* pfile;
 pfile = fopen("/tmp/code","r");                              //open file
 char *stringBuffer = (char *)malloc(SIZE * sizeof(char));   //dynamic string

  char ch;
  int i = 0;
  ch = getc(pfile);                                          //read file
  while(ch != EOF)                                           //until end
  {                                                          //pass into string 
        counter++;
        stringBuffer[i] = ch;
        ch = getc(pfile);
        i++;
    }

    fclose(pfile);                                              //resize string

    int stringSize = (int)(sizeof(stringBuffer)/sizeof(char));
    stringBuffer = (char *)realloc(stringBuffer,(stringSize * sizeof(char)));

    printf("the string works: %s \n",stringBuffer);

    int intger = (int)*stringBuffer;    //this is what i want to work!!!!

    //but more like
    //int intger = (int)stringBuffer; 

    printf("the intger doesn't work if more than 1 decimal place: %i \n",(intger - 48));

    free(stringBuffer);
    return(0);
    }
~                                                                                                                                          
~
```

I do realize I could 
    1.cast the char as int & convert from ASCII to real number
    2.multiplier each (now int) by is decimal place (determined by array position)
    3.add ints together
    for example (warning this code is kinda ugly, I haven't look twice at it yet and is just a test so far)

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <math.h>

    #define SIZE 500

    int main(void)
    {
    FILE* pfile;
    pfile = fopen("/tmp/code","r");                                            

    char *stringBuffer = (char *)malloc(SIZE * sizeof(char));                 

    char ch;
    int i = 0;
    ch = getc(pfile);                                                         
    while(ch != EOF)                                                          
    {
        stringBuffer[i] = ch;
        ch = getc(pfile);
        i++;
    }

    fclose(pfile);

    int stringSize = (int)(sizeof(stringBuffer)/sizeof(char));
    stringBuffer = (char *)realloc(stringBuffer,(stringSize * sizeof(char)));

    printf("the string works: %s \n",stringBuffer);
    int multi;
    int sum;

   for(int x =0; x < stringSize; x++)
   {
      int intger = ((int)stringBuffer[((stringSize - 1) - x)] - 48);

      if( x != 0 )
      {
        multi = (int)pow(10,x);
        sum += ( multi * intger );
      }
      else
        sum += intger;
    }
    printf("the int works: %i \n",sum);
    free(stringBuffer);
    return(0);
    }
```

but still casting as string as int would be nice(I assume c++ has this?).

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: atoi is a standard library function that probably does what you want?

Comment: `(int)*stringBuffer` dereferences just the first character in the string and promotes it to an int. If you want the first 4 characters (or whatever your `sizeof(int)` is) to be converted to a single integer is you can do `*(int*)stringBuffer` But I am not sure if that is what you want. Do you want to convert the decimal string to an integer?

Comment: `atoi()` is in `stdlib.h`. This is probably what you want as nneonneo says

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya except, you can't, aliasing violation, alignment error and whatnot.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Yes, I was trying to understand what he is trying to do. If he wants decimal string to integer conversion atoi is the way to go. If he has a 4 byte integer's binary data in the file, he would have to do what I said. Question is very unclear to me.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya *If you want the first 4 characters (or whatever your sizeof(int) is) to be converted to a single integer is you can do `*(int*)stringBuffer`* That violates strict aliasing.  You *can not* safely treat a `char *` as an `int *`. Do that on a system that has actual alignment restrictions on things like `int` and your program will likely fail with a `SIGBUS` or similar.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Fine, will have to do it through a Union of char[sizeof(int)] and int then. That should be fine because the entire Union will be aligned to the same alignment as that of int and that would be a correct type punning.

Answer (score 0):

It does not work the way you expect.

**==>** In case of a statement like

```
  int intger = (int)stringBuffer;
```

Casting a "string" (or, the pointer to the first element of the `char` array) to `int` is highly implementation defined behaviour and if not properly supported by the implementation, will cause undefined behaviour.

**==>** OTOH, a statement like

```
 int intger = (int)*stringBuffer;
```

is an attempt to dereference the first memory location pointed by `stringBuffer` and then cast that value to `int` (which would have been done implicitly anyway). This does not convert the whole string content to an integer type. That is why you see something like

> *the integer doesn't work if more than 1 decimal place: % [......]*

**Solution:** From your problem statement, looks like you can make use of [`strtol()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol) or variants. You need to read a whole line with `fgets()` or similar and then, (after parsing, if required) pass that to `strtol()` to convert to a `long int`.

After that, notes about your code:

- In `while(ch != EOF)` loop body, you have an uncontrolled iteration with `i`, it may lead to out of bound memory access.
- `int stringSize = (int)(sizeof(stringBuffer)/sizeof(char));` is not going to give you the *string* size, you need to null-terminate the *string* and use `strlen()` to get the length of the string.

That said, some of general comments:

- Always check the return value of `fopen()` (or for that matter, any library function) before using the return value.
- [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).
- [`getc()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getc) returns an `int` and a return value of `EOF` is not going to fit in a `char`. You need an `int` to hold that.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the DV, guess I can then ask for a comment also to improve the post?

Comment: I am surprised to see two downvotes for this answer?

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy many people losing their keys, I guess. :)

Comment: lol wish i read this a hour ago I've been trying to figure out what was going on with my EOF, thanks! I don't see how  I "have an uncontrolled iteration with i" can you please clarify thanks a ton. Yeah strtol(), or the fscanf() mentioned above should work fine defiantly very over complicated, but I have to learn the stdlib some how!

Comment: @jhonythompson regarding the uncontrolled iteration, look at the indexing. You have statically allocated `500` bytes of memory, but you pu no bounds on the value of `i`. For some input, it is quite possible that there's no `EOF` till index `499` and then, the value of `i` will be increased to `500` and that index would cause the out of bound access.

Comment: *defiantly very over complicated*, that is the correct way of doing it. So I guess we are stuck with that.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of your example, you could simplify the whole code using the `fscanf` function.

```
FILE* pfile;
pfile = fopen("/tmp/code","r");

int intger;
fscanf(pfile, "%i", &intger);

fclose(pfile);
```

If you need both the string and the integer, you can use the `sscanf` function in the same way, or the `strtol` function.